# Изменение первоначального значения слова

Tags: лексика

В своем произведении "Живой как жизнь" К.И. Чуковский писал, что раньше слово ***обязательно*** носило значение "любезно", а уже позже приобрело значение "непременно".

Как в русском языке называются слова, которые поменяли свое лексическое значение, но при этом само слово не изменилось?

Comment: О каком слове речь-то?!

Comment: О слове обязательно.

Comment: Не думаю, что есть какая-то необходимость в специальном термине, поскольку это явление  происходит с огромным количеством слов в языке (языках). То есть это скорее норма, чем исключение.